# put the remaining first days in last month mysql

Tags: php, mysql, date

```
$contract_start_date = '2016-09-01';
$contract_end_date = '2017-10-31';
$no_of_months = 1 + (date("Y", $contract_end_date) - date("Y", $contract_start_date)) * 12; 
$no_of_months += date("m", $contract_end_date) - date("m", $contract_start_date); 
$no_of_months = intval($no_of_months);
```

Here I have got a contract which is for a year. Now, I have two pay methods: Advance and Deferred.

> **Advance method**, I get the bill for every first date of every month(say y-m-01),

and in

> **Deferred method**, I get the bill for every last date of every month(y-m-last_date),

if the contract starts exactly at first date of any month and any year.

If example my new contract starts at '2016-09-15' and ends at '2017-10-14',
then the bill generated should be like this: 
Advance method: 
1st bill:

```
$contract_start_date ='2016-09-15'value(('for the period between '2016-09-15' to '2016-09-31''));
```

then the other bills will be of date **'y-m-01'** for very month till `$contract_end_date`. Now the remaining 14 days of first_month should be generated after the `$contract_end_date`, say I have to get the bill for 14 days on `'2017-11-01'`. So how can I achieve this? Please give some tips.